# Vector of structure returns only last value

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference, structure

Sorry I can't paste the full code but I will try my best to explain the problem. I have a vector of structure. I am passing the vector to a function which fills the vector with structure and returns the vector. But when I try to access the vector elements,  I get only the last element inserted. I think the problem is somewhere that I am storing the address of the structure and hence vector only retains the last value but i am not sure how to correct this.

Here is my structure:

```
 struct NA
 { element1;
   element2;
 };
```

Here is how I pass my vector after declaring it:

```
Vector<NA> del;
func(del);
```

Here is my function: ( q is a variable having results from a stored procedure

```
 func(Vector<NA> &dels)
{  
  NA& del(*new NA);
  while(q.nextquery())
   {
     while(q.nextrow())
     {
       q.bind(del.element1);
       q.bind(del.element2);
       dels.insert(&del);
     }
    return dels.entries()
 }
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE] as required please.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: There are few limitations in my company for which I cant use tools like intellij and eclipse. If this was java I would have definitely debugged my code but here it is difficult, would expect a solution if possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NA& del(*new NA);
while(q.nextquery())
     dels.insert(&del);
```

Obviously, you are creating only one `del` object, but you insert it many times in the same vector. At the end, all you vector's entries will point to the same object.

What you want is probably to create a new `del` object for each entry in your vector. therefore, put the creation statement inside the loop.

```
func(Vector<NA> &dels)
{  
  while(q.nextquery())
   {
     while(q.nextrow())
     {
         NA& del(*new NA); // <-- Here
         q.bind(del.element1);
         q.bind(del.element2);
         dels.insert(&del);
     }
     return dels.entries()
 }
```

Comment: ok let me try this once, I thought of this but wont this consume a lot of space and create many structure pointers?

Comment: @user3274263 if this is what you want, you have to. I can't tell there are workarounds to to save some memory because I don't know enough about your  overall code. This should fix your current issue for the time being :)

Answer (score 0):

`func()` is pushing multiple copies of a single pointer to a single dynamically allocated object into the vector. Each loop iteration is modifying that same object, so every entry in the vector will end up pointing to the data of the last query record that was read.

Try something more like this instead:

```
func(Vector<NA> &dels) {
    while(q.nextquery()) {
        while(q.nextrow()) {
            NA *del = new NA;
            q.bind(del->element1);
            q.bind(del->element2);
            dels.insert(del);
        }
    }
    return dels.entries();
}
```

On the other hand, why are you storing pointers in the vector?  And using a non-standard vector class?  It would be safer to store actual objects into a standard `std::vector` class instead:

```
void func(std::vector<NA> &dels) {
    while(q.nextquery()) {
        while(q.nextrow()) {
            NA del;
            q.bind(del.element1);
            q.bind(del.element2);
            dels.push_back(del);
        }
    }
}
```